# Public URL didn't appear

Tags: python

I have to try create public url from my local url with local tunnel, but it just print the IP, not the url. my code is like this

```
import subprocess

import threading

import time

import socket

import urllib.request

def iframe_thread(port):

    while True:

        time.sleep(0.5)

        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        result = sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1', port))

        if result == 0:

            break

        sock.close()

        from colorama import Fore, Style

    print(Fore.GREEN + "\nLocaltunnel Endpoint IP is:", Fore.RED, urllib.request.urlopen('https://ipv4.icanhazip.com').read().decode('utf8').strip("\n"),"\n",Style.RESET_ALL)

    p = subprocess.Popen(["lt", "--port", "{}".format(port)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    for line in p.stdout:

        print(line.decode(), end='')

threading.Thread(target=iframe_thread, daemon=True, args=(7860,)).start
()
```

Hopefully someone tell me the troubleshoot for this